# AngularJS: 'google-maps': call directive in infoWindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angularjs-directive

I'm using http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/ to display a map in my angular Application.
I have a general controller for my page getting a Json.
to display markers, i'm using $watch in the scope cause I will do real time and the markers positions can change.

```
$scope.model  = new Model 'api/now.json'
$scope.state  = new DState

$scope.$watch ->
  markers = []
  _($scope.model.objects).each (obj) ->
    markers.push
      latitude:   obj.latitude
      longitude:  obj.longitude
      infoWindow: "<info-window>SHOULD NOT DISPLAY CAUSE DIRECTIVE</info-window>"

  markers
  , (newValue) ->
    $scope.state.map.markers = newValue
  , true
```

My directive is basic:

```
am.directive "infoWindow", ->

restrict: 'E'
template: "<div>IN DIRECTIVE</div>"
replace: true
```

My Html page calling the map:

```
#dashboard{ng:{controller: 'dashboardCtrl'}}


  #map.google-map{center:     'state.map.center',
                  zoom:       'state.map.zoom',
                  markers:    'state.map.markers',
                  draggable:  'true'}
```

And The DState Factory to define the state:

```
.factory 'DashboardState', (Media) ->
  class DashboardState
    defaults:
      map:
        center:
          latitude:   45.764043
          longitude:  4.835659
        zoom: 10
        markers: []
      selectedObj: null

    constructor: (initialData) ->
      _(@defaults).extend initialData
      _(this).extend @defaults
```

So, my display here in my infoWindow is

> SHOULD NOT DISPLAY CAUSE DIRECTIVE

But I should have what is in my directive:

> IN DIRECTIVE

My directive is not called ... Do you have an idea?

It's a double question here, I would like to set the **SelectedObj** of my factory to the Obj himself. Do you have an Idea how to handle the event click on marker and where to place it to call the method who could assign my obj to SelectedObj?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I think the <info-window> is not reevaluated by angular to transform the directive, it directly display the raw html.. I still didn't find a solution for the moment

Comment: What if you use $compile to manually compile that html string (for infowindow), and then bind it to the scope. That should get angular to handle the directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. get the latest version of angularjs-ui-maps
2. Use the tempalteUrl property of the  directive - you can add your directives inside the template (see how this is done in the example.html that's included in the source).

This way you can avoid any custom compilation of html

I'd faced a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843463/angularjs-using-a-directive-in-google-maps-marker-window

In case you find any other approach, please do post it.

HTH